# How to set query.limit on Background Job

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

As you know there is a burst limit when you are running Background Jobs in parse- your jobs can only run for a maximum of 15 minutes. 
I have a class that contains over 50K objects and let's say I want set a default value to all the objects because I recently added a column. The background job keeps timing out... 
When I try to use query.limit(10) for example, the job won't run at all.

Here's the code for the background job:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("defaultVerified", function(request, status) {

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var counter = 0;

  var query = new Parse.Query("Games");
  query.limit(10);
  query.each(function(game) {

      game.set("verified", "NO");
      if (counter % 100 === 0) {
        // Set the  job's progress status
        status.message(counter + " games processed.");
      }
      counter += 1;
      return game.save();
  }).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
    status.success("Games update completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    status.error("Something went wrong.");
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't appear to be iOS related. If your problem is iOS related, then add relevant code to your question, please. (You might have better luck adding a JavaScript tag.)

Comment: I can't see how this change should affect whether the job is run. I'm guessing there is something else that is wrong, or you're experiencing an oddity. Maybe try the same on another search that will yield fewer results, and then try to use limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't limit `each()` as it is designed to process every single record in a job. Instead you should use `find()` which will respect your limit.

More information is found in the docs here:

http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#each

> The query may not have any sort order, and may not use limit or skip.

Comment: Thanks Timothy, the limit is respected using find instead of each.

Comment: Hello @MarcosReyes, could you explain how you updated your 50k records with the query limit? I tried to do the same but was not able to... 
Either I use each, but I it's going to be too long, either I use find, but then there's the 1000 limit...

Comment: @SebastienC. I had to create a job, instead of a regular function, that would run every 15 minutes. Every time the job ran, I would query 1000 different records. Add a boolean to the 50K records for example and only set the boolean to TRUE once you have made the necessary updates. So as part of your query, only query records where the boolean is undefined or FALSE. Also, if you have a free Parse account, you can only run one job at a time- keep that in mind... Hope this helps!